# What does the SSIS CODEPOINT value 26 represent

Tags: ssis

In one of the existing SSIS projects, I found a Condition Split with an expression of CODEPOINT(column)==26.

But I couldn't find what is the value "26" represents. When I searched the CODEPOINT for alphabet letters it starts from 65 and for 0-9 it starts from 45.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CODEPOINT Expresion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137696.aspx) merely states the following

> Returns the Unicode code point of the leftmost character of a character expression

Exploring wikipedia turned up [Unicode encodings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Unicode_encodings)

> The first 128 Unicode code points, U+0000 to U+007F, used for the C0 Controls and Basic Latin characters and which correspond one-to-one to their ASCII-code equivalents

Sweet, putting that together and consulting the [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) table allows me to determine that 26 is [SUB/Substitute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character) control character. Ctrl-Z for those really wanting to try this at home (and working under a Unix(tm) variant)

Comment: You can skip the side-trip to ASCII and go directly to a [Unicode table](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf).